# How to set the from name in smtp IIS 7

Tags: iis, smtp

How do I set the name of the sender for all emails on SMTP windows 2008 rc2?

My emails are coming froom noreply@mydomain.com but I can't figure out how to set the name that they come from.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to your mail client? or to the mail server?
If you are referring to the mail client you are using, add the email address as in your contact addresses and change the name.

Comment: have you configured the mailboxes of all the users? each users must have their own mailboxes, and own user names. Initially, the username set for a user's mailbox in the mail server will be the default sender name (when that user sends an email)

Comment: hmm it's for automated messages from noreply@mydomain.com. In IIS manager, I double click on SMTP Email. Then under email address I write: My Name <noreply@mydomain>.   Are you saying I need a user for the noreply mailbox?